# Handling Display Size change

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-8.0-oreo, android-7.0-nougat

I am migrating my app target SDK Version to android oreo.

One of the changes which might affect the app is that if the Display size of the device is changed then the app targeting Android Nougat and above will be notified as if there is a change in orientation of the device. Below is the source.

> When the device density changes, the system notifies running apps in
>   the following ways:
>
> If an app targets API level 23 or lower, the system automatically
>   kills all its background processes. This means that if a user switches
>   away from such an app to open the Settings screen and changes the
>   Display size setting, the system kills the app in the same manner that
>   it would in a low-memory situation. If the app has any foreground
>   processes, the system notifies those processes of the configuration
>   change as described in Handling Runtime Changes, just as if the
>   device's orientation had changed.
>   If an app targets Android 7.0, all
>   of its processes (foreground and background) are notified of the
>   configuration change as described in Handling Runtime Changes.

Now my app has a longrunning process which runs in an Async TSak in an Android Activity. Which means that the App has an AsyncTask which is inside the Activity Code.

I create a Dialog box on the start of the Async Task and hide it when the Async Task has done its work.

Now suppose the users start the task and then goes to the setting and changes the Display Size then return back to my app then the dialog box of the app is gone by the Async Task is still performed till the end which mean that the user might think that the app has finished the task but whereas the app would be actually performing the task. But my Activity is also responding as if restarted except that Async Task is running.

My app's orientation locked to portrait.

How should I handle such a scenario? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT: This is the scenario

1) App Start

2) Main Screen

3) Users Press A Button

4) AsyncTask inside Main Screen Started

5) A Dialog Box is shown with the progress of task

6) User Minimizes the App and Goes to setting

7) Changes the Display Size/Density or changes the Font Size of the device

8) My App is called by the OS in such a way as if the device rotation is changed

9) Then the user returns back to the app

10) But the dialog box shown is no more being shown

11) But the async Task is running in the background and is still performing its task

12) The task is actually done but the user thinks that the task is still not done.

Comment: Your question is little bit unclear. could you please edit question with small **gif?** so we can have better idea.

Comment: @RumitPatel Thanks for the reply. Sorry, I cannot attach a gif of the app but I have written the scenario stepwise. Can you please have a look.

Comment: Your question put focus on display size changes, but it seems that you are just not handling properly configuration changes (something you should have done from the start if you were supporting screen rotations). You should improve your code so that 1) the dialog is started again on rotation (this should happen with a DialogFragment) and 2) let the AsyncTask find the new dialog (which you can do for example hosting it in a fragment with setRetainInstance). If you want to do it even better you can set the AsyncTask in a ViewModel and post the results to the observers.

Comment: @gicci Yes, you are right. Can you please provide a sample code so that it is better for me to handle this?

Comment: your question is unclear you want to perform the task in background or the notification is gone after user comes back is your problem??

Comment: @swanandkeskar Performing is done by using an AsyncTask which is already set up and running. But I also provide a dialog box with the progress which shows the progress of the task. But the problem is that after a change in Display Size/Font Size the dialog box is gone and activity is restarted but the AsyncTask is still running without the user being aware that his work will still be done.

Comment: @Rahulrr2602 alright so you want the dialog box to stay right? it should be disappearing even when you rotate the screen as your activity is destroyed and recreated on configuration change 
Posing my answer , do like and accept if it solves ur problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your on_resume() method verify the screen size and the font size have not changed. If they have, adjust, remove and recreate, your dialog box appropriately. This is similar to handling orientation changes while suspended (adding font size as a condition).

EDIT:

Add `android:configChanges="fontScale|density"` to your manifest file.

```
static int fontScale = 1;
static int densityDpi = 0;

public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
  if (newConfig.fontScale != fontScale) {
    // destroy and recreate dialog adjusting for font size.
    fontScale = newConfig.fontScale;
  }
  if (newConfig.densityDpi != densityDpi) {
    // destroy and recreate dialog adjusting for new screen size.
    densityDpi = newConfig.densityDpi;
  }
}
```

---

It would probably be better to utilize notifications for the async task, since they are unaffected by config changes and are not terminated in low memory conditions.

Comment: What about the device density changes? Can you please provide sample code?

Comment: A device density change is the same as a screen size change. The screen width and height will change. As far as providing code, I will give a generic sample, that, most likely, will not be applicable to your code, since you have not provided any.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The perfect answer which was required. Just one more doubt that if `onConfigurationChanged` is not used then also the app remains the same as before(This case is better for me). Is that the right behavior and the same would be across many devices? Anyway thanks once again for the answer.

Comment: This is the only solution that will work across multiple devices and configuration changes. I am sorry, if this is not optimal, but is is the best that can be done.

Comment: Thank. And your solution is the best. Thanks once again

Answer (score 2):

When you rotate the phone, your activity is actually destroyed and recreated. This includes your dialog. There are two ways to fix it:

1) Turn off this "helpful" functionality. If you don't have different layouts for landscape and portrait its what I'd suggest. Add android:configChange="orientation|resize" to your activity in the manifest.

2) Implement onSaveInstanceState/onRestoreInstanceState and have a variable that says whether or not you need to recreate and relaunch the dialog.

Suggestions:
Try using WorkManager to schedule the task and also ViewModel from the android architecture components which helps to retain the state even after the configuration changes

Comment: Thanks for the answer, But for the orientation change I never had an issue but the main issue was for Density or Font Change.